# create javascript object from for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a sortable javascript object that looks like this:

```
myArray = [
  {name: "Jones, James", ef: "35", mem: "2018.12.10"},
  {name: "Smith, Paul", ef: "35", mem: "2018.09.12"},
  {name: "Washington, George", ef: "35", mem: "2018.08.16"}
];
```

I also plan to sort myArray() by name.

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.name - b.name;
});
```

THE JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function store() {
  var myArray = [];

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NAME = document.getElementById('P' + i).value;
    EF = document.getElementById('E' + i).value;
    MEM = document.getElementById('M' + i).value;

    // This code doesn't seem to add records to myArray()

    myArray.push({
      name: 'NAME',
      ef: 'EF',
      mem: 'MEM'
    });
  }

  console.log(myArray.length);
}

store();
```

I sorted the myArray:

```
0: {name: "Abercrombie, Bill", rank: "1537", uscf: "9999", ef: "3", exp: "2019.01.12", …}
1: {name: "Baken, Clif", rank: "1802", uscf: "9999", ef: "3", exp: "2019.09.18", …}
2: {name: "Kukla, Ollie", rank: "2014", uscf: "0920", ef: "", exp: "2019.08.12", …}
3: {name: "Lincoln, Abraham", rank: "2023", uscf: "0119", ef: "", exp: "2019.09.06", …}
4: {name: "Washington, George", rank: "1563", uscf: "9999", ef: "3", exp: "2019.01.16", …}
```

How do I iterate over the sorted myArray() to populate the form? I think I need something like this:

```
console.log(myArray.length);

for (i = 1; i <= myArray.length; i++) {
// where id "P1" is the name input field in the form which we are populating
document.getElementById("P" +i).value = myArray[name];

}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?kindly include that in OP

Comment: I am new to localStorage and I don't know what I'm doing. I need assistance. I can do some things but this pretty advanced. I'm really in over my head, guradio.

Comment: You can store an array or single object in one localStorage key by using JSON.stringify() to set and JSON.parse() in the get. Then loop over that array/object and set values within the loop with very little code needed

Comment: I think: localStorage.setItem('SP4', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("P4").value))); (is correct). But how do I bring the local storage into a sortable array with JSON.stringify ?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to sort by? You mention _"P1-P48"_ but what does that relate to? Is it the values in your `<input>` elements or their `id` attributes. It's very confusing because your IDs are `P4`, `E4` and `X4` which really doesn't make sense given _"P1-P48"_

Comment: What would you like the result to look like?

Comment: I have a form with input ID's that I want populated. The basic form is at https:/verlager.com

Comment: That tells me nothing. What's the point in sorting anything if you just want to populate a bunch of `<input>` values?

Comment: I want to sort  by player name which is ID Px where "x" is an integer 1-48

Comment: Please provide examples. Show what you currently have and show what you'd like the result to be

Comment: I'd like the result to be a sorted list. Sorted by player name.

Comment: All these comments mean absolutely nothing. Please edit your question with actual examples

Comment: If I could do that, I would, I really would.

Comment: You can. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53217929/edit) to show some examples of actual data and what you'd like the result to look like. It should not be difficult

Comment: I am lost. Simply in over my head.

Comment: OK I edited the original question. I don't understand the difficulty of this issue. User types names. I want the names sorted based on local storage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183334/discussion-between-verlager-and-phil).

Comment: I get it. Sorry, I didn't understand what you met by "give more examples". My bad.

Comment: were you be able to fix the problem?

Comment: No, I'm still in the dark. Sorry for my incompetence.

Comment: I don't see what any of this (or the previous question edit) has anything to do with local storage. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Do you want to read the data in a filled out form on https://verlager.com/ and then sort it by name? Or do you want to read some data from local storage, sort by name and fill out the form?

Comment: I took the initiative of trying to solve this myself. In the interest of simplicity, I omitted the local storage code because it is so simple yet unneeded. We need this sorted so that we can spot duplicate entries.

Comment: *I want to create a sortable JavaScript object*. Object keys can't be sorted. You're out of luck with that. Use an Array if you require sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use use jQuery, why not build `myArray` like this:

```
for (n = 1; n <= 3; n++) {
  myArray.push({
    name: $('#P' + n).val(),
    ef: $('#E' + n).val(),
    mem: $('#M' + n).val()
  });
}
```

For sorting the `myArray`: (credits to the MDN [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19326174/9217760))

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => {
  let nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
  let nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
  return nameA < nameB ? -1 : nameA > nameB ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Then for putting back the `myArray` values into the corresponding `input` fields:

```
myArray.forEach((item, i) => {
  let n = i + 1;
  $('#P' + n).val(item.name);
  $('#E' + n).val(item.ef);
  $('#M' + n).val(item.mem);
  // ... do the same for other fields
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the code:

- you are **not declaring the variables** `NAME`, `EF`, `MEM`.

  This means [these are implicit globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword) (!) and your code might have unintended side-effects.

  **Solution:** use `var`, `let` or even better, `const` to declare these variables in the block scope.
- You are **pushing strings, not variables**.

  when you do `myArray.push({name: 'NAME'})` you are saying put the string value `'NAME'` as the value for `name`.

  **Solution:** remove the quotes, use `name: NAME`, or even better, change the variable to `name` and use the [ES2015 shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions):

  `myArray.push({name, ef, mem});`
- [prefer to use `const` if you are not reassigning variables. Use `let` in all other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086682/428486).

  This simply makes your code more robust as they have fewer quirks than using the old `var`.

Example:

```js
function store() {
  const myArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Replaced getElementByID since it's not relevant
    const name = 'some name';
    const ef = 'some string';
    const mem = 'some value';

    // This code doesn't seem to add records to myArray()

    myArray.push({name, ef, mem});
  }

  console.log(myArray.length);
}

store();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Steps:

1- Make [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) []

2- Sort its items using sort function

remember that localStorage sets and get strings so parse them using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method

Sort Function: (this sorts alphabetically with property name)

[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Demo:

```
let result = array.sort((a.name, b.name) => a.name - b.name)
```

Comment: How can this work...? I have localStorage with SP1 to SP48 as sort items. I don't see any reference to this in the expression you have kindly supplied.

Comment: First we have the populate a sortable javascript object and then fill in the form from the sorted list.

Comment: Yes... I updated the answer.. you can mark it as solution if it helps

Comment: A simple array is not useful in this case. Please see the orginal question. I have to sort the "array" and then iterate over the "array" to extract vars and populate the form.

Comment: Sorting object isn't usually useful see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value ...so sorting array can be your solution

Comment: @Microsmsm `a.name - b.name` works well with numeric values, but for strings, you can use `a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0` just as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19326174/9217760) and the MDN [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description).