# Fill table rows with values from an array

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I'm creating a table using JavaScript DOM and I need to insert all the values from the array (thValues) to each of the TH contained in a TR (table row). How I can do it?

```js
let thValues = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6"];

let pickTableZone = document.getElementById("tableDetails");
let table = document.createElement("table");

pickTableZone.appendChild(table);
table.setAttribute("class", "table table-responsive-sm table-striped");

let tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
table.appendChild(tableBody); //adding tbody to table

//for the length of thValues create table rows
for (let i = 0; i < thValues.length; i++) {
    let tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
    tableBody.appendChild(tableRow); //adding TR to TBODY

    let tableHead = document.createElement("th");
    tableRow.appendChild(tableHead); //adding TH to TR
    tableHead.setAttribute("scope", "row"); //adding attributes to TH

    let text = document.createTextNode(thValues[0]); //Assign each text from the thValues in each TH from the TR's
    tableHead.appendChild(text); //adding text to TH

    let tableData = document.createElement("td");
    tableRow.appendChild(tableData); //adding TD to TR

    let textInTD = document.createTextNode("Time 1");
    tableData.appendChild(textInTD); //adding text to TD
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableDetails">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two loops: one to populate the head row with `th` cells; one to create the body rows with `td` cells.  As it stands, you're creating a new row for each header value instead of putting all of them in a single row.  You're also putting your head cells in `tbody` instead of `thead`.

Here is how you could create the header row.

```js
const thValues = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6"];

const pickTableZone = document.getElementById("tableDetails");
const table = document.createElement("table");

pickTableZone.appendChild(table);
table.setAttribute("class", "table table-responsive-sm table-striped");

const tableHead = document.createElement("thead");
table.appendChild(tableHead); //adding thead to table

const headRow = document.createElement("tr");
tableHead.appendChild(headRow); // Row for the head cells.

// Add each header.
for (let i = 0; i < thValues.length; ++i) {
  const headCell = document.createElement("th");
  headRow.appendChild(headCell); //adding head cell to head row

  const text = document.createTextNode(thValues[i]);
  headCell.appendChild(text); //adding text to TH
}

const tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
table.appendChild(tableBody); //adding tbody to table

// for each row of data
//   add a tr to tbody
//   for each column (e.g. thValues.length)
//     add a td to the tr
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableDetails"></div>
```

It's not clear from your post what you want to put in the `tbody` since you're just repeating "Time 1" over and over.  I've therefore left some pseudocode for populating the body.

As an aside, you should use `const` instead of `let` unless you plan on reassigning the variable ([for a number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086682/3977276)).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! I realized what I was missing in my code, I forgot to replace zero with i in document.createTextNode(thValues[i])

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was missing in my code to achieve what I wanted. I forgot to add an i to `let text = document.createTextNode(thValues[i]);`

```js
let thValues = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6"];

let pickTableZone = document.getElementById("tableDetails");
let table = document.createElement("table");

pickTableZone.appendChild(table);
table.setAttribute("class", "table table-responsive-sm table-striped");

let tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
table.appendChild(tableBody); //adding tbody to table

//for the length of thValues create table rows
for (let i = 0; i < thValues.length; i++) {
    let tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
    tableBody.appendChild(tableRow); //adding TR to TBODY

    let tableHead = document.createElement("th");
    tableRow.appendChild(tableHead); //adding TH to TR
    tableHead.setAttribute("scope", "row"); //adding attributes to TH

    let text = document.createTextNode(thValues[i]); //Assign each text from the thValues in each TH from the TR's
    tableHead.appendChild(text); //adding text to TH

    let tableData = document.createElement("td");
    tableRow.appendChild(tableData); //adding TD to TR

    let textInTD = document.createTextNode("Time 1");
    tableData.appendChild(textInTD); //adding text to TD
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableDetails">
```