# display user typed text in JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to copy what the user have typed in a text area into a `<p>` tag, but it does not work. Once the user clicks the save button, the text should be displayed in the `<p>` tag.

Here is my code:

```html
<div>
        <div>
            <h2>You are to write your tought here in this test box and click save</h2>
            <label for="heiku" class="label">Your Heiku</label>
            <br />
    
            <textarea class="textarea" id="heiku" name="heiku" rows="4" cols="50">
                Write your Heiku here
            </textarea>
            <button class="button" id="submit" Onclick="Save()">Save</button>
    
            <p class="p" id="heiki_input"></p>
    
    
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        let heiku = document.getElementById("heiku").value;
        let heiku_input = heiku
    
        function save(){
            
            document.getElementById("heiku_input").innerText = heiku_input;
            console.log(heiku_input);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Move your `let haiku` stuff into the `save()` function and make it `onclick="save()"` (lowercase). Also `heiki_input` is misspelled. That should be `heiku_input`. Also, it's spelled "haiku" but that has nothing to do with the problem. `tought` -> `thought`, `test box` -> `text box`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solving the error in code

There were some typos in your code

1. `Onclick` event listener should be in simple letters as `onclick`
2. Since the function is name is defined as  `save` in JavaScript you can use `onclick="save()"` in HTML
3. If you get the value of `textarea` outside the function in the beginning of the script, only the initial value of `textarea` will be assigned to `heiku` variable. To get the value of `textarea` once the user clicks on the button you should move

   `let heiku = document.getElementById("heiku").value;`
   into the `save` function.

Corrected code will look like below...

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>You are to write your tought here in this test box and click save</h2>
        <label for="heiku" class="label">Your Heiku</label>
        <br />

        <textarea class="textarea" id="heiku" name="heiku" rows="4" cols="50">
            Write your Heiku here
        </textarea>
        <button class="button" id="submit" onclick="save()">Save</button>

        <p class="p" id="heiku_input"></p>


    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function save(){
        let heiku = document.getElementById("heiku").value;
        let heiku_input = heiku
        document.getElementById("heiku_input").innerText = heiku_input;
        console.log(heiku_input);
    }
</script>
```

### Achieving the desired result

- However the above code might not produce the accurate results you were looking for. The initial text inserted into the `textarea` tag in HTML is also counted as it's value by default. To display the initial text you have inserted inside the `textarea` to work as a placeholder you can include it in  `placeholder` attribute.
- Also I am not sure why you are once assigning the value of `textarea` to variable `heiku` and then again assigning `heiku` to `heiku_input`.
  If you prefer to perform more actions with the value of `textarea` you can simply assign the value of `textarea` to `heiku` only.
- To make your code more into [ES6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp) standards you can use `const` to define the `save` function and use `const` instead of `let` to assign the value of `textarea` field to `heiku_input`. [Read more about the usage here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086682/13833218)

Here is the preferable snippet to use.

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>You are to write your tought here in this test box and click save</h2>
    <label for="heiku" class="label">Your Heiku</label>
    <br />

    <textarea class="textarea" id="heiku" name="heiku" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Write your Heiku here"></textarea>
    <button class="button" id="submit" onclick="save()">Save</button>

    <p class="p" id="heiku_input"></p>


  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const save = () => {
    const heiku = document.getElementById("heiku").value;
    document.getElementById("heiku_input").innerText = heiku;
    console.log(heiku);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>You are to write your tought here in this test box and click save</h2>
        <label for="heiku" class="label">Your Heiku</label>
        <br>
    
        <textarea class="textarea" id="heiku" name="heiku" rows="4" cols="50">
                Write your Heiku here
         </textarea>
         <button class="button" id="submit" onclick="save()">Save</button>
    
         <p class="p" id="heiku_input"></p>
    </div>
</div>
    
<script>
        
    function save(){
          
        document.getElementById("heiku_input").innerText = document.getElementById("heiku").value;
        console.log(heiku_input);
     }
</script>
```

This should work. Pretty much you just had a few spelling mistakes amongst the elements and weren't grabbing the elements each time.

You also do not need to bother saving the elements either unless they are to be used later.