# Having trouble building multi-step form using the Slick carousel. I am missing something in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I am trying to create a multi-step form using the Slick carousel for a subscription product. The form is supposed to ask what gender, size, items, and then billing. At the end of the form I want to display the choices of the user with a link that links to the product based on the user's choices.

I found a website that does pretty much what I want - https://www.gruntstyle.com/pages/club-grunt-style

Here is what I have so far - https://codepen.io/Alex-Baker-the-decoder/pen/MWxdKBa

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Define products
    const products = [
      {
        gender: "male",
        size: "s",
        product: "SPIKE SHIRT BOX",
        billing: "1st Month",
        productName: "Men’s Small Shirt - Monthly",
        link: ""
      },
      {
        gender: "female",
        size: "2XL",
        product: "shirt",
        billing: "monthly",
        productName: "Women’s 2XL Shirt - Monthly",
        link: ""
      }
    ];
  
    // Hide all steps except the first one initially
    $(".join-club-steps:not(:first)").hide();
  
    // When a radio button or select option is changed
    $('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
      var currentStep = $(this).closest(".join-club-steps");
      var nextStep = currentStep.next(".join-club-steps");
  
      // Show final slide if on the last step and valid
      if (nextStep.length === 0 && isStepValid(currentStep)) {
        showFinalSlide();
      } else {
        navigateSteps(this, "next");
      }
    });
  
    // Function to check if the step is valid
    function isStepValid(step) {
      var stepId = step.attr("id");
      switch (stepId) {
        case "join-step-gender":
          return $('input[name="gender"]:checked').length > 0;
        case "join-step-size":
          return $('input[name="size"]:checked').length > 0;
        case "join-step-product":
          return $('input[name="product"]:checked').length > 0;
        case "join-step-billing":
          return $('input[name="billing"]:checked').length > 0;
        default:
          return true;
      }
    }
  
    // Function to display the final slide with user selections
    function showFinalSlide() {
      var selectedGender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
      var selectedSize = $('input[name="size"]:checked').val();
      var selectedProduct = $('input[name="product"]:checked').val();
      var selectedBilling = $('input[name="billing"]:checked').val();
  
      // Update final slide with user's selections
      $("#selectedGender").text(selectedGender);
      $("#selectedSize").text(selectedSize);
      $("#selectedProduct").text(selectedProduct);
      $("#selectedBilling").text(selectedBilling);
  
      // Hide all steps and show final slide
      $(".join-club-steps").hide();
      $(".final-slide").show();
    }
  
    // Function to navigate steps
    function navigateSteps(element, direction) {
      var currentStep = $(element).closest(".join-club-steps");
      var stepIndex = $(".join-club-steps").index(currentStep) + 1; // Get current step index
      var targetStepIndex = direction === "next" ? stepIndex + 1 : stepIndex - 1;
  
      if (
        direction === "next" &&
        targetStepIndex <= $(".join-club-steps").length
      ) {
        showStep(targetStepIndex);
      }
    }
  
    // Function to show a specific step
    function showStep(stepNumber) {
      $(".join-club-steps").hide(); // Hide all steps
      $(".join-club-steps")
        .eq(stepNumber - 1)
        .show(); // Show the target step
      highlightCurrentStep(stepNumber);
    }
  
    // Function to highlight the current step in the progress bar
    function highlightCurrentStep(stepNumber) {
      $(".circle").removeClass("active"); // Remove active class from all circles
      $(".circle[data-step='" + stepNumber + "']").addClass("active"); // Add active class to the current circle
    }
  
    // Navigate to a specific step by clicking on the progress bar
    function navigateToStep(stepNumber) {
      showStep(stepNumber);
    }
  
    // Reset button functionality
    $("#reset-btn").click(function () {
      resetForm();
    });
  
    // Function to reset the form and go back to the first step
    function resetForm() {
      $('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", false);
      $("select").val($("select option:first").val());
      showStep(1); // Show the first step
    }
  
    // Initial setup
    highlightCurrentStep(1); // Highlight step 1
  });
```

```css
/* Center everything */
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1500px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

/* Style each step */
.join-club-steps {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 0px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Style the progress bar */
#join-club-progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#join-club-progress-bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#join-club-progress-bar ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f1402b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: #f1402b;
  color: #fff;
}
.gender_male {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}
.gender_male:hover {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #f1402b;
  padding: 25px;
  cursor: none !important;
  background-color: #f1402b;
}
.gender_female {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}
.gender_female:hover {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #f1402b;
  padding: 25px;
  cursor: none !important;
  background-color: #f1402b;
}
.size_club {
  font-size: 40px;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}
.size_club:hover {
  font-size: 40px;
  border: solid 2px #f1402b;
  padding: 25px;
  cursor: none !important;
  background-color: #f1402b;
}
.product_club {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 280px;
  color: #fff;
}
.product_club:hover {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #f1402b;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 280px;
  cursor: none !important;
  background-color: #f1402b;
}
.billing_club {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 280px;
  color: #fff;
}
.billing_club:hover {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #f1402b;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 280px;
  cursor: none !important;
  background-color: #f1402b;
}
#product_detail_club {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.feq_club {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 280px;
  color: #fff;
}
.feq_club:hover {
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 2px #f1402b;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 280px;
  cursor: none !important;
  background-color: #f1402b;
}
#feq_detail_club {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.hide_radio {
  display: none;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: inherit;
  background-color: #f1402b;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="steps-container" class="container">
<img src="https://ucarecdn.com/ffcf27ab-90b2-46ac-ae8d-83b11d8ada7c/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/ClubAdx%20Logo%20w%20box.png" width="500">
<div id="steps" class="slick-initialized slick-slider">

    <!-- Step slides -->
    <div class="join-club-steps" id="join-step-gender">
    <!-- Step 1 Content: Pick Gender -->
    <h2>Step 1: Pick Gender</h2>
    <label class="gender_male"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male</label>
    <label class="gender_female"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female</label>
    </div>
    <div class="join-club-steps" id="join-step-size">
    <!-- Step 2 Content: Pick Size -->
    <h2>Step 2: Pick Size</h2>
    <label class="size_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="size" value="s"> S</label>
    <label class="size_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="size" value="m"> M</label>
    <label class="size_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="size" value="l"> L</label>
    <label class="size_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="size" value="xl"> XL</label>
    <label class="size_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="size" value="2xl"> 2XL</label>
    </div>

    <div class="join-club-steps" id="join-step-product">
    <!-- Step 3 Content: Pick Product -->
    <h2>Step 3: Pick Product</h2>
    <label class="product_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="product" value="SPIKE SHIRT BOX"> SPIKE SHIRT BOX<br><span id="product_detail_club">Receive One Shirt Each Month</span></label>
    <label class="product_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="product" value="SPIKE HAT BOX"> SPIKE HAT BOX<br><span id="product_detail_club">Receive One Hat Each Month</span></label>
    <label class="product_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="product" value="TROPHY COMBO BOX"> TROPHY COMBO BOX<br><span id="product_detail_club">2 Items - Receive One Shirt AND One Hat Each Month </span></label>
    <label class="product_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="product" value="DEAL BOX"> DEAL BOX<br><span id="product_detail_club">Hat OR Shirt from PAST Designs to Save You Money Each Month Alternates Between Shirt and Hat</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="join-club-steps" id="join-step-billing">
    <!-- Step 4 Content: Pick Billing Frequency -->
    <h2>Step 4: Pick Billing Frequency</h2>
    <label class="billing_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="billing" value="1st Month"> 1st Month $1.00<br><span id="product_detail_club">THEN $28 MONTHLY 6 MONTH MIN AGREEMENT</span></label>
    <label class="feq_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="billing" value="Monthly"> Monthly<br><span id="feq_detail_club">$28.00 every month, no contract</span></label>
    <label class="feq_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="billing" value="3 Months"> 3 Months<br><span id="feq_detail_club">$25.50/SHIRT $75.60 ONE TIME </span></label>
    <label class="feq_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="billing" value="6 Months"> 6 Months<br><span id="feq_detail_club">$23.80/SHIRT $142.80 ONE TIME</span></label>
    <label class="feq_club"><input class="hide_radio" type="radio" name="billing" value="12 Months"> 12 Months<br><span id="feq_detail_club">$22.40/SHIRT $268.80 ONE TIME</span></label>
    </div>

    <!-- Final slide to show user selections -->
    <div class="join-club-steps final-slide">
    <h2>Your Selections</h2>
    <p>Gender: <span id="selectedGender"></span></p>
    <p>Size: <span id="selectedSize"></span></p>
    <p>Product: <span id="selectedProduct"></span></p>
    <p>Billing Frequency: <span id="selectedBilling"></span></p>
    <a href="" id="product-link" target="_blank"><button id="join-now-btn">Join Now</button></a>
    <button id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="join-club-progress-bar">
    <ul>
    <li>
        <div class="circle" data-step="1">1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="circle" data-step="2">2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="circle" data-step="3">3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="circle" data-step="4">4</div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

I have Verified that the IDs used to update the final slide content (selectedGender, selectedSize, selectedProduct, selectedBilling) match the IDs specified in my HTML.

I have checked the event binding for radio button changes is working correctly and that the change event is being triggered as expected.

The form will get to the Final slide, but will not display the user inputs and link to the product it matches to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slightly tweak your `nextStep` within the `change` event handler for your radio buttons.

Instead of

```
  $('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
    var currentStep = $(this).closest(".join-club-steps");
    var nextStep = currentStep.next(".join-club-steps");

    // Show final slide if on the last step and valid
    if (nextStep.length === 0 && isStepValid(currentStep)) {
      showFinalSlide();
    } else {
      navigateSteps(this, "next");
    }
  });
```

do this

```
  $('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
    var currentStep = $(this).closest(".join-club-steps");
    var nextStep = currentStep.next(".join-club-steps:not(.final-slide)"); // <--- this was added

    // Show final slide if on the last step and valid
    if (nextStep.length === 0 && isStepValid(currentStep)) {
      showFinalSlide();
    } else {
      navigateSteps(this, "next");
    }
  });
```

The `:not(.final-slide)` slide is needed because without it, `nextStep` is picking up the element with the `.final-slide` class. The reason for that pickup is that it also has the `.join-club-steps` class.

If you're not sure about my explanation, do the following. As the first thing in your Javascript code, before the `$(document).ready(...)`, add something like `var tmp;`. Then, within your `$('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {...});` add `tmp = $(this);`. This will set the `tmp` variable to whatever was tested in the last step, and you can then manually, via your browser's console, do something like

```
console.log(tmp);
console.log(tmp.closest('.join-club-steps'));
console.log(tmp.next('.join-club-steps'));
```

to better understand what was going on. Of course, once you do, you don't need to leave `tmp` and its use in your code.

As an aside - you should probably address the [CLS issue](https://web.dev/articles/cls) which happens when changing steps.

---

**EDIT**

As suggested by Mark Schultheiss in the comments, since `currentStep` and `nextStep` won't be changed during the lifetime of the context within which they were used (internal variables within an anonymous function), instead of using

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
    var currentStep = $(this).closest(".join-club-steps");
    var nextStep = currentStep.next(".join-club-steps:not(.final-slide)");

    // rest of your code for this event handler
});
```

you can change it to look like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
    const currentStep = $(this).closest(".join-club-steps");
    const nextStep = currentStep.next(".join-club-steps:not(.final-slide)");

    // rest of your code for this event handler
});
```

This can also be done in other parts of the code, where variables are declared within your functions (`isStepValid`, `showFinalSlide`, `navigateSteps`).

This isn't an absolute must - your code will work with `var` as well as with `const`, in this case. But it is advisable to make this change - please see [the following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086682/6133426) to get a better understanding why.

Comment: consider suggesting declarations like `const currentStep` since those will not change.